# What is PostgreSQL equivalent of user_tables from oracle

Tags: postgresql-11

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables;
SELECT sequence_name FROM user_sequences;
```

which one is correct pg_tables or information_schema.tables.Please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

`pg_tables` and `information_schema.tables` both contain information about tables. `information_schema` is the standard ANSI SQL way to query the data dictionary, so using it can make your queries more portable if you ever want to switch DBMSs.

Comment: which command I  can use to get  tables owned by the current user?